# Maven module build using python

Tags: python, maven

I'm writing a script to for maven build of sub modules. Below is my code-

```
dirl = "C:\\Users\\arupaul\\git\\application\\helios-parent\\"+ modToBeBuilt[0]
os.chdir(dirl)
args = ['mvn', 'clean install']
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The modToBeBuilt has got the list of module names to build. I'm getting the below error:-

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
```

I'm new to python so I chose this way. If you know of a better approach do let me know. The script is not allowed to be in the project repo so I need to keep it in a separate place.

Comment: Is it erroring out  on os.chdir or sub process call?

Comment: Why not using Maven to build all modules? Is this a multi module build? Please show pom files or maybe a github example project...

Comment: its coming on .chdir.

Comment: Currently its configured as a maven multi module build. over time as the repo became huge i'm trying to build only those modules which have changes

Comment: You know things like `mvn -pl ...` etc. ? What does huge mean? How long does it take? What is really the time consumer? The build or the Tests? Have you checked that? Have you thought about running in parallel via `mvn -T 3 ..` ?

Comment: @ArunavaPaul that tells me the dirl string is not a valid path and should be directory. What is the output if you  print dirl

Comment: Follow @khmarbaise advice and try to solve your problem within Maven.

Comment: Is Maven (mvn.bat, mvn.cmd) on your PATH?